# Como saber se uma imagem realmente foi compartilhada no Instagram?

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugin, instagram-api

Estou desenvolvendo um app que compartilha uma imagem de dentro dele para o `Instagram`, é em `Ionic 3`. Na documentação do plugin do `Instagram` pra `Ionic` diz que a função retorna se a imagem foi ou não compartilhada, porém, na prática só obtenho de retorno a mensagem `"Share cancelled"`, mesmo com a imagem sendo realmente compartilhada.

Como faço para obter o retorno que desejo?

Segue um trecho da função:

```js
file.readAsDataURL(url, this.imgname).then(res => {

  this.insta.share(res, this.texto).then((data) => {
    alert("Data insta share>: " + JSON.stringify(data));

  }).catch( error => {
    alert("error : " + JSON.stringify(error));
  })

}).catch(err => {})
```

[Link do plugin Instagram](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/instagram/)

Comment: A mensagem : "Share cancelled" é exibida dentro do then ou no catch?

Comment: é exibida dentro do catch

Comment: Se entrou no catch é pq não foi compartilhada, seja lá qual foi o motivo. Só vai entrar no then quando deu sucesso

Comment: exato, mas entra no catch mesmo se a imagem é compartilhada

Comment: Estranho, vou tentar reproduzir. Coloca o link do plugin na pergunta, por favor.

Comment: pronto, coloquei